# Are there specific file extensions that aren't compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility, file-format

I am using Ubuntu version 12.04.2 LTS

Are there any specific programs or file extensions that are not compatible with Ubuntu? Can all .exe extensions be run on Ubuntu? I have just started using this OS so my experience is next to nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by specific file extensions? It really depends on what is the programming language in the file and the libraries available on Ubuntu and whether Ubuntu can compile the source code and if there is an engine that is able to convert the code to binary (understandable by the computer). I think that is what matters.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It really depends on what kind of file you want to ask about. Each will deserve it's own question. For the matter of EXE-files. Those are meant to be run on a Windows System. There is Wine which can run certain programs. It's not for the faint at heart though. You will have better chances if you try to find a native Linux program for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wine` can be used to run windows programs(i.e .exe files).most programs will run easily with no or little twerks.

there could be hundreds(if not thousands) of file extensions that are not compatible with Ubuntu out of the box.this is because anyone can create different extensions for there private use,or for use with a specific programs.for example a program `Anki` uses `.apkg` format.naturally this file format would be incompatible with windows or osx or any other os.

But that's not all,Ubuntu comes with a set of very good apps,and other apps like `7zip`
support most of file formats which are frequently used in day-to-day life.

---

### for how-to on Wine

[official  wine wiki](http://wiki.winehq.org/HowTo)
 [how-to-use-wine‎](http://speedofmac.com/tutorials/how-to-use-wine.html%E2%80%8E)
[how to use wine on linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Wine-on-Linux)

Answer (score 1):

No there are no incompatible file extensions. Ububntu doesn't really care about file extensions and just sees a file.

It treats every file the same and doesn't break them up into different sorts that need to be treated differently.

The programs and apps themselves know how to deal with file extensions if they come across them, but if you ask a Ubuntu app to open a file it will not worry about the extension unless its own program logic needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Ubuntu technically does not work with extensions but checks the 1st few characters inside the file to determine what that file is. In Linux/Ubuntu it is perfectly correct to have a file named "picture.txt" or "picture.exe". In Linux/Ubuntu clicking the file will open and show a picture.

You can not run software from another system on a different system (software made in Java is an exception). You need that software's download for that system to use it. So you can use VLC on Ubuntu and on Windows and on Mac OS but each has it own installer with all the needed software in it.

For windows software you can use a compatibility layer called WINE. It simulates windows DLLs and does a fair job in getting windows software to run. It is not the best method but can be useful. I would myself rather dual boot or use VirtualBox.